# Can't make request as an Authenticated user in Laravel with Vue.js

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js, middleware

I log in as an **`ADMIN`** and `Auth::guard('admin')->check()`  returns `true` but then I hit the button `DELETE`  in vue.js like this :

```
<button type="submit" v-on:click="remove(story.id)">Delete </button>
```

then in my `remove` function I make request to my destroy method to delete a story:

```
fetch(`/api/stories/${id}`,{
         method : 'DELETE'
     })
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(res => console.log(res))
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

then in my controller and inside a `destroy` method with is protected by the `auth:admin` middleware, It returns `false` which shows that I'm `not authenticated` but when I hit button `edit` in the same page it goes to `edit` method which is protected by the middleware too but it works fine:

```
<a class="button is-light" v-bind:href=`stories/${story.id}/edit`>Edit</a>
```

what is the difference between these two making request with these buttons ?
How can I tell laravel that I'm making request with the authenticated user but inside Vue.js

Comment: The **api** routes do not go through the session by default, so it appears that the user is not logged. You can edit the middleware to include the sessions or use another route with the **web** middleware.

Comment: which version of Laravel are you using?  also how you are setting the Auth Headers while making the DELETE request?

Comment: @thefallen thank you very much, I put the route in the web.php so it's OK now :)